# tikz node newline gap too large

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
 \node[text width=3cm,rotate=90] at ([shift={(0ex, 0x)}] pic cs:fig1) {{\tiny{First\\Line}}};
```

Either setting the width to be small or using `\\` will split the text but it has a huge gap between First and Line. Enough to stick my thumb between them. It's as if whatever space would be used with `\tiny` is being used. I want the gap between the two lines to be almost nil. I could use another node and position it but that seems like overkill.

Comment: the baseline skip is a property of the paragraph and in your fragment the scope of `\tiny` has finished before the paragraph ends so you will get tiny text on a normal baseline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your example works just fine if you change `\tiny` to the option `font=\tiny`. That corrects the baselines.

[image: The compiled example]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
 \tikz \node[text width=3cm,rotate=90,font=\tiny] at (0,0) {{First\\Line}};  
\end{document}
```